# Symfony2 working with database

Tags: php, database, symfony

I'm working on my first project on Symfony2. I have some problems with basic actions.
I've generated entity of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_category` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Now I want to select all rows from this table. How should I do that? I tried to add new method in my entity.

```
public function getAll()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT *
        FROM product_category'
    );

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

... but I'm pretty sure that this is bad way cause I would have to use this method in context of concrete entity. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine uses [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) not SQL and you don't need a custom query get all the records, you can use the default repository:

```
// e.g. in a controller
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product');
$products = $repository->findAll();
```

This is an example right from [the symfony docs.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database) You should really read the docs first, these projects have greate docs.

Comment: Thanks, I just read that. But after doing that in $products I have a large set of variety of data.

Comment: Looks like I don't have to convert result into array or something just pass it into the template as written here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138915/using-doctrine-database-object-in-a-template